# How do I can assign element of string value to int value?

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to write a program, that will sum numbers of a string value(for example I have string value `"123"` and I'd like sum these numbers to get int value "5").
*Additional information*: I need to do it by **recursion**.
How do I can do that?
I tried this code:

```
static void SumString(string num, ref int index, ref int result) 
{
    if(index >= num.Length - 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        return;
    }    
            
        
    char[] arr = new char[num.Length];

    arr[index] = num[index];

    result += Convert.ToInt32(arr[index]);

        

    index++;

    SumString(num, ref index, ref result);
}
```

Comment: Use `int.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: I tried it, but here an error:1503: can't convert from "char" to "string"

Comment: `int.Parse(num)` should work.

Comment: Is the number in the expression always a single character?

Comment: Nope, it's "5121"

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable.Compute

```
using System.Data;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var v = dt.Compute(num,"");
```

Comment: Yeah, but actually I need to solve it with recursion(

Comment: Than you have not asked a proper question

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of problems.

`Convert.ToInt32(num[index]` will give you value 49 which is asci value of 1.

Then you are not ignoring the `+` character as well. so you need to skip it.

The correct solution would be

```
static void SumString(string num, ref int index, ref int result)
{
    if (index >= num.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        return;
    }

    if (index % 2 == 0)
        result += (Convert.ToInt32(num[index]) - '0');

    index++;

    SumString(num, ref index, ref result);
}
```

you can use an expression evaluator also if looking for some external library.

https://github.com/codingseb/ExpressionEvaluator